# How to map all OPTION requests to a certain controller in play 2?

Tags: java, playframework, routes

How can i route all OPTION requests to a certain controller in play 2+? 
I have this route in routes file :

```
OPTIONS    /   @controllers.CORSController.preFlight
```

I also need to route all OPTION requests to the same controller like :

```
OPTIONS /dev/upload  @controllers.CORSController.preFlight
OPTIONS /some/path   @controllers.CORSController.preFlight
...
```

how can i achieve this with one route or some other global way (like overriding onRouteRequest method?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wild card path to catch all routes for a particular HTTP method as in the example below:

```
OPTIONS   /*path  @controllers.CORSController.preFlight(path)
OPTIONS   /       @controllers.CORSController.preFlight
```

Notice the `path` parameter in the route definition which is mandatory to compile the route file. You'll have to add an overloaded `preFlight` method to accept a String parameter even though you won't have to use it in its body.

```
public Result preFlight(String path) {
    // insert your body
}

public Result preFlight() {
    return preFlight("");
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i have tested wild card solution, it works fine for pathes like localhost:900/some/path but now it is not woking for just "/" . (localhost:9000/)

Comment: In this case the best thing you can do is to write a separate route for the / path and reuse the preFlight method body. I reckon it's still better than creating a separate route for each URL in the app.